# Why do air flight code-shares exist?

Tags: airlines, code-share

It seems that code-shares are extremely common nowadays, with any flight on a non-budget airline having at least one. However I could never understand why airlines bother with code shares in the first place. I'm pretty sure they can sell connecting tickets on partner airlines without a code-share and having several codes creates some confusion when trying to find your flight at the airport.

So what's the rationale for having a code-share agreement in the first place?

Comment: Yes, that wikipedia article gives both sides in painstaking detail.

Comment: Beyond optics, the most obvious difference between a codeshare flight and some interlining/resale agreement is that different rules apply, especially for rewards programs.

Comment: Codeshares exist because the airlines find them to be comercially advantageous. Are you asking that, or why a codeshare flight has more than one flight number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put quite simply it allows an airline to offer more destinations to its customers.

It is marketing bragging rights, saying JR Air flies to 1200 destinations, rather than JR Air flies to 500 destinations but we can book you with our buddies to another 700.

JR Air frequent flyers can get standardized points all the way to their destination without trying to figure out cross airline point schemes.

JR Air can set fares between city pairs, as they have contracted for seats at a set fare(s), rather than looking at prices that are available when you book.

JR Air can instantly confirm seats because they have contracted for XX seats on each code share flight and sell from their contracted allotment rather than querying what is currently available each time.

Comment: A short note regarding the frequent flyer points: whether your argument holds depends on the airline alliance. Star alliance awards points based on the operating carrier, not the marketing carrier. And even worse: the number of miles credited depends on the mapping between the fare classes of the airlines as well, so it's incredibly complicated to figure that out in that case. So for the Star Alliance, it's quite the opposite.

Comment: @DCTLib - When dealing with airlines there are exceptions to EVERYTHING.  Even your statement, as United awards points the same for their flights as well as UA ticketed code share flights.

Comment: @Tom -- I suspect that's because many UA code shares are flown by regional carriers which don't run off their own ticket stock, so to speak, so they don't have "native" frequent flyer programs either.

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject - Those flights aren't "code share", they are UA flights operated by a sub-contractor.  "Code Share" is when UA sells some seats on a UA flight to other airlines, who then resell those seats under their name.

Comment: The marketing part makes sense. Otherwise it can all work in the very same way without having a second visible "partner" code.

Comment: @Tom -- well, they're kind of quasi-code-share as they have an IATA flight number from the operating carrier, even if the operating carrier doesn't print ticket stock

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject - The regional feeder flights are not considered code share in any sense of the word.  They carry a UA1234 flight number; ATC (Air Traffic Control) tracks the flight as UAL1234 tail number X123YZ; the plane is painted in United colors; the flight crew and ground crew usually wear United uniforms.  The contractor operates the flight solely for United.  And many regionals are actually owned in full or in part by the major airline they contract for.  That said, United may sell seats on those flights to other airlines for them to resell as a code share.

Comment: @Tom -- wrong on most points.  They carry a UA number for marketing purposes, but *also* a flight number for the operating carrier (take AX4601/UA4601 for instance), and use the *operating carrier's radio callsign* -- that'd be "Waterski 4601" on the radio, and use Trans States metal (albeit painted in United Express livery).  The flight crew and cabin crew will be Trans States personnel (most likely.  I *know* it's true for SkyWest operated Delta Connection flights as that's the case I've been on), and Trans States is owned by a holding company independent of UAL.

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject - yes the plane belongs to the subcontrator, while wearing United paint, yes the crew works for the subcontractor while wearing United uniforms, but it is still not a "code share".  The fact that they use AX1234 instead of UA1234 as a call sign is simply a technicality, as flight AX1234 does not exist on its own in the public travel window.  You can not buy seats on flight AX1234, it does not exist in any booking system.  United owns 100% of the seats on that flight.

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject - A catchall travel industry terms for this is "white label", where the marketing airline or tour company, subcontract the operation of a travel service to another company.  The sub-contracted company operates as if they were staff of the marketing company.  My company does quite a bit of this for adventure travel companies.  We wear the staff outfit, sign post our vehicles and trip documents with XYZ Tours name.  As far as the guests (and the public) is concerned we are XYZ Tours.  We are not "code sharing" our tours, we are operating their tours.

Comment: @Tom -- I will agree that the precise nature of a subcontract regional carrier operation (such as Trans States) is debatable (Trans States may or may not be in a position where they could have a flight that was marketed through both AAL and UAL).  There are also independent regional operations, however -- Great Lakes Airlines is an example (they have their own ticket stock, and also codeshare with UAL), and these *still* don't have their own frequent-flyer programs and such.

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject - as I said in my first comment - When dealing with airlines there are exceptions to EVERYTHING.